# Google map loads on localhost ,but fails to load on online server

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps

i have been able to deploy google map on localhost, it loads all coordinates with success.
But when i upload the same code to my server, it completely fails to load.I tried all i could, am really at a lost here.

```
<html>
<head>

<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery-1.6.2.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery-ui-1.8.14.custom.min.js'></script>

<style>

    BODY {font-family : Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; color: #000000; font-size : 13px ; }

    #map_canvas { width:100%; height: 100%; z-index: 0; }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" /></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
jQuery(document).ready( function($){
        function closeInfos(){
            if(infos.length > 0){
                infos[0].set("marker",null);
                infos[0].close();
                infos.length = 0;
            }
        }

    //Get data, and replace it on the form
    var geocoder;
    var map;
    var markersArray = [];
    var infos = [];

    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var myOptions = {
          zoom: 9,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);    

    function deleteMarkers() {
      for (var i = 0; i < markersArray.length; i++) {
        markersArray[i].setMap(null);
      }

      markersArray = [];
    }

setInterval(function(){
    $.get('ajax_gp_gps.php', function(data){        
     var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var encodedString;
    var stringArray = [];
    encodedString = data;
    stringArray = encodedString.split("****");

    var x;
    for (x = 0; x < stringArray.length; x = x + 1)
    {
        var addressDetails = [];
        var marker;
        addressDetails = stringArray[x].split("&&&");

        var lat = new google.maps.LatLng(addressDetails[1], addressDetails[2]);
        //alert(image + " " + addressDetails[1] );
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({ 
            map: map, 
            position: lat,
            content: addressDetails[0]
        });
        markersArray.push(marker);
        google.maps.event.addListener( marker, 'click', function () {
            closeInfos();
            var info = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: this.content});
            // where I have added .html to the marker object.
            //infowindow.setContent( marker.html);
            info.open(map,this);
            infos[0]=info;
        });
        bounds.extend(lat);
    }

    map.fitBounds(bounds);


    });
},1000);

});     
</script>

</head>
<body>

<?php include_once("ajax_gp_gps.php"); ?>

<div id='input'>
  <input type="hidden" id="encodedString" name="encodedString" value="<?php echo $encodedString; ?>">
</div>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Make sure you've updated your paths (for your assets > jquery and jquery-ui)

Comment: All the paths are in place, i think it may be coming from something i may be over looking...just can put a finger on it.

Comment: Could you check the chrome/firefox tools (F12) and see if anything is coming up?

Comment: Please explain what you mean @James Lalor. I right clicked and checked the source code, it loads nothing, If that is what you mean.

Comment: Not the source code, right click and inspect element on chrome, see if there are any errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check google API if your online domain has access to call it or not.

Comment: These are my scripts - <script type='text/javascript' src='jquery-1.6.2.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='jquery-ui-1.8.14.custom.min.js'></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" /></script> , am thinking it may be my connection script...

Comment: Thanks for your time guys, its the connection script to MySQL db. I changed it and every thing is fine. Thanks. Do i have to marked this question as solved?

Comment: So actually it was never the issue with google api. I think you should at least vote for my answer.

Comment: i wish i could, but i don't have permission yet to vote. Your effort @DeeJay is well appreciated.

Comment: Thanks decongh, let me know if you face any other issues with your deployment. While deploying outside your development environment, make sure that the server variables are in place, and permissions to the filing system is correct based on the application. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and it was simple fix: If you page uses https, make sure google maps url within the script tag also uses https:

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).